# android- how to make a shape drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

I want to make a `drawable` like this :
[image]

this is my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/red_home" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/green2" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

It's not how I wanted it to be ... I don't want the radius in the top left corner... how can I make it like the first image ?

Comment: Radius will not work for you because your image has straight line, i suggest you can rotate your shape

Comment: Radius is for curves.  If you wanted a rounded corner for a button, you'd use that.  I wouldn't use a shape drawable for this, I'd use a vector drawable.  Really there's very few reasons to use shapes now that vector is supported.

Comment: Create a svg file for this would be a better choice.